# Planning route from point A to point B and avoiding a specific area in google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have been searching if it is possible to create such a solution in Google Maps?

1. define an area on the map (the entire area or a line drawn along selected streets)
2. The user determines the route from his current location to the destination
3. the route is determined so that skirted previously designated streets or area

For example, on the map we determine an area of closed streets (eg, due to the organization of the event) and the application helps in determining access roads bypassing the closed area.
Such as "Avoid highways" and "Avoid toll roads" option, but for my own particular areas or streets.

Answer (score 0):

"Roadblock" functionality is not currently available in the directions service. [open enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214)